# Inserting Distinct elements into a Binary Heap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

The number of ways , in which numbers 1,2,3,4,5 can be inserted into binary heap, such that resultant binary heap is min heap ?

Answer = 8

==========================================================================

My take - Since it's a Min heap, the minimum value will be at root.

This will be the min heap as

```
                             o   -------> root will be chosen in 1 way
                            / \
                           o   o 
                          / \ 
                         o  o
```

-> Left sub tree will be **4C3*1*2** way as again root will get min value and left and right child can get any value.

-> Lastly the right sub tree => 1C1 = 1

Totally - 1*4C3*1*2*1 = 8. Is this approach correct?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A056971

Comment: @MBo Is my approach wrong?

Comment: No, it is correct. Link contains code for more general recurrence.

Comment: @MBo Thanks dear fellow! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your are correct answer is 8. Let us consider all the arrangements.

Let `LST = left subtree` and RST = `right subtree`

first -1 is fixed at root(since 1 is the lowest element).

1st way: we can have(2,3,4) in LST and only 5 at the RST : here (2,3,4) can be arranged in 2 ways by keeping 4 as root in LST

2nd way :(2,3,5) at LST which itself can be done in 2 ways and keep 4 at RST

3rd way: (2,4,5) at LST and 3 at RST

4th way : (3,4,5) at LST and 2 at RST

total ways = 2*2*2*2 = 8 ways

Comment: @Geeklovenerds there is nothing wrong with your approach too friend :)

Comment: Thanks Brother! May peace be with you! ::)))